# how to call multiple views on one url in pinax

Tags: python, django, pinax

> **Following is view.py which includes `signup/loginview`**

**view.py**

```
from accounts.forms import SettingsForm
from accounts.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from accounts.models import SignupCode, EmailAddress, EmailConfirmation, Account, AccountDeletion
from accounts.utils import default_redirect,user_display


class SignupView(FormView):

    template_name = "account/signup.html"
    template_name_ajax = "account/ajax/signup.html"
    template_name_email_confirmation_sent = "account/email_confirmation_sent.html"
    template_name_email_confirmation_sent_ajax = "account/ajax/email_confirmation_sent.html"
    template_name_signup_closed = "account/signup_closed.html"
    template_name_signup_closed_ajax = "account/ajax/signup_closed.html"
    form_class = SignupForm
    form_kwargs = {}
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    messages = {
        "email_confirmation_sent": {
            "level": messages.INFO,
            "text": _("Confirmation email sent to %(email)s.")
        },
        "invalid_signup_code": {
            "level": messages.WARNING,
            "text": _("The code %(code)s is invalid.")
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_user = None
        kwargs["signup_code"] = None
        super(SignupView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(default_redirect(self.request, AccountAppConf.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
        if not self.is_open():
            return self.closed()
        return super(SignupView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_open():
            return self.closed()
        return super(SignupView, self).post(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(SignupView, self).get_initial()
        if self.signup_code:
            initial["code"] = self.signup_code.code
            if self.signup_code.email:
                initial["email"] = self.signup_code.email
        return initial

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return [self.template_name_ajax]
        else:
            return [self.template_name]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = kwargs
        redirect_field_name = self.get_redirect_field_name()
        ctx.update({
            "redirect_field_name": redirect_field_name,
            "redirect_field_value": self.request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name),
        })
        return ctx

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SignupView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.form_kwargs)
        return kwargs

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        signals.user_sign_up_attempt.send(
            sender=SignupForm,
            username=form.data.get("username"),
            email=form.data.get("email"),
            result=form.is_valid()
        )
        return super(SignupView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.created_user = self.create_user(form, commit=False)
        # prevent User post_save signal from creating an Account instance
        # we want to handle that ourself.
        self.created_user._disable_account_creation = True
        self.created_user.save()
        email_address = self.create_email_address(form)
        if AccountAppConf.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED and not email_address.verified:
            self.created_user.is_active = False
            self.created_user.save()
        self.create_account(form)
        self.after_signup(form)
        if AccountAppConf.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL and not email_address.verified:
            email_address.send_confirmation()
        if AccountAppConf.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED and not email_address.verified:
            return self.email_confirmation_required_response()
        else:
            show_message = [
                AccountAppConf.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL,
                self.messages.get("email_confirmation_sent"),
                not email_address.verified
            ]
            if all(show_message):
                messages.add_message(
                    self.request,
                    self.messages["email_confirmation_sent"]["level"],
                    self.messages["email_confirmation_sent"]["text"] % {
                        "email": form.cleaned_data["email"]
                    }
                )
            self.login_user()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self, fallback_url=None, **kwargs):
        if fallback_url is None:
            fallback_url = AccountAppConf.SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL
        kwargs.setdefault("redirect_field_name", self.get_redirect_field_name())
        return default_redirect(self.request, fallback_url, **kwargs)

    def get_redirect_field_name(self):
        return self.redirect_field_name

    def create_user(self, form, commit=True, **kwargs):
        user = User(**kwargs)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if username is None:
            username = self.generate_username(form)
        user.username = username
        user.email = form.cleaned_data["email"].strip()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def create_account(self, form):
        return Account.create(request=self.request, user=self.created_user, create_email=False)

    def generate_username(self, form):
        raise NotImplementedError("Unable to generate username by default. "
            "Override SignupView.generate_username in a subclass.")

    def create_email_address(self, form, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("primary", True)
        kwargs.setdefault("verified", False)
        if self.signup_code:
            self.signup_code.use(self.created_user)
            kwargs["verified"] = self.signup_code.email and self.created_user.email == self.signup_code.email
        return EmailAddress.objects.add_email(self.created_user, self.created_user.email, **kwargs)

    def after_signup(self, form):
        signals.user_signed_up.send(sender=SignupForm, user=self.created_user, form=form)

    def login_user(self):
        # set backend on User object to bypass needing to call auth.authenticate
        self.created_user.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
        auth.login(self.request, self.created_user)
        self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

    def is_open(self):
        code = self.request.REQUEST.get("code")
        if code:
            try:
                self.signup_code = SignupCode.check(code)
            except SignupCode.InvalidCode:
                if self.messages.get("invalid_signup_code"):
                    messages.add_message(
                        self.request,
                        self.messages["invalid_signup_code"]["level"],
                        self.messages["invalid_signup_code"]["text"] % {
                            "code": code
                        }
                    )
                return AccountAppConf.OPEN_SIGNUP
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return AccountAppConf.OPEN_SIGNUP

    def email_confirmation_required_response(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            template_name = self.template_name_email_confirmation_sent_ajax
        else:
            template_name = self.template_name_email_confirmation_sent
        response_kwargs = {
            "request": self.request,
            "template": template_name,
            "context": {
                "email": self.created_user.email,
                "success_url": self.get_success_url(),
            }
        }
        return self.response_class(**response_kwargs)

    def closed(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            template_name = self.template_name_signup_closed_ajax
        else:
            template_name = self.template_name_signup_closed
        response_kwargs = {
            "request": self.request,
            "template": template_name,
        }
        return self.response_class(**response_kwargs)


class LoginView(FormView):

    template_name = "account/login.html"
    template_name_ajax = "account/ajax/login.html"
    form_class = LoginUsernameForm
    form_kwargs = {}
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())
        return super(LoginView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return [self.template_name_ajax]
        else:
            return [self.template_name]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = kwargs
        redirect_field_name = self.get_redirect_field_name()
        ctx.update({
            "redirect_field_name": redirect_field_name,
            "redirect_field_value": self.request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name),
        })
        return ctx

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.form_kwargs)
        return kwargs

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        signals.user_login_attempt.send(
            sender=LoginView,
            username=form.data.get(form.identifier_field),
            result=form.is_valid()
        )
        return super(LoginView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.login_user(form)
        self.after_login(form)
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def after_login(self, form):
        signals.user_logged_in.send(sender=LoginView, user=form.user, form=form)

    def get_success_url(self, fallback_url=None, **kwargs):
        if fallback_url is None:
            fallback_url = AccountAppConf.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        kwargs.setdefault("redirect_field_name", self.get_redirect_field_name())
        return default_redirect(self.request, fallback_url, **kwargs)

    def get_redirect_field_name(self):
        return self.redirect_field_name

    def login_user(self, form):
        auth.login(self.request, form.user)
        expiry = AccountAppConf.REMEMBER_ME_EXPIRY if form.cleaned_data.get("remember") else 0
        self.request.session.set_expiry(expiry)
```

> **Following is `account/url.py` given by Pinax**

**account/url.py**

```
from accounts.views import SignupView, LoginView, LogoutView, DeleteView
from accounts.views import ConfirmEmailView
from accounts.views import ChangePasswordView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetTokenView
from accounts.views import SettingsView,Signup_login


urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^signup/$", SignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
    url(r"^login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name="account_login"),
    url(r"^logout/$", LogoutView.as_view(), name="account_logout"),
    url(r"^confirm_email/(?P<key>\w+)/$", ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name="account_confirm_email"),
    url(r"^password/$", ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name="account_password"),
    url(r"^password/reset/$", PasswordResetView.as_view(), name="account_password_reset"),
    url(r"^password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$", PasswordResetTokenView.as_view(), name="account_password_reset_token"),
    url(r"^settings/$", SettingsView.as_view(), name="account_settings"),
    url(r"^delete/$", DeleteView.as_view(), name="account_delete"),
    url(r"^signup.login/$", Signup_login.as_view(), name="Signup_login"),
)
```

> **And following is my project's `app/url.py`**

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",                                       

      url(r"^$",SignupView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="account_signup"),
      url(r"^$", LoginView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="account_login"),
      url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r"^account/", include("accounts.urls")),
)
```

**What I am trying to do:** call both views on `homepage.html`. It contains two forms in single html.

Comment: what? i am trying to do ,calling both views on homepage.html it contains two forms in single html buts overwritting forms when i am calling account_signup first then in both forms its giving me only signupview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  Try to wrap your head around what is going on between the browser and the webserver.  A URL identifies content that the server will return to the client.  Calling 2 "views" violates that principle.

What you really want to do is create a new URL, or modify the templates to put both forms on the same page.  I'd probably rename SignupOrLoginView and do the signup work in that single view.

This would be easier to understand in a functional view instead of a class based view which seems to constrain you to a single form.